# wrong output when there is tag is inside flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have problem with flexbox. Whenever I put some tag inside the format (visible output) is wrong.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="line1"><div class="one">IMG</div></div>
  <div class="line2">Some text here.</div>
  <div class="line3">Cause of A tag [Cause of A tag] <br><a> (this is inside A tag) [(this is inside A tag)] </a><br> flexbox is displayed wrong [flexbox is displayed wrong]</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container
{background:black;
padding:10px;
display:flex;}

.line1
{border:2px solid blue;
padding:10px;
background:yellow;}

.line2
{display:flex;
align-items:center;
align-self:stretch;
border:3px solid blue;
padding:10px;
background:yellow;}

.line3
{display:flex;
align-items:center;
align-self:stretch;
border:3px solid blue;
padding:10px;
background:yellow;}

.one
{padding:10px;
background:red;}
```

What I want to do is to **align-items:center;** at **.line3** but I need to set up **display:flex;** to do so. But the the format is gone... and  has some space around.

https://jsfiddle.net/4025gLo8/4/ - wih flex (item are centered but there is  problem)

https://jsfiddle.net/b8amyfog/4/ - without flex (proper format, but without align-items:center;  or align-self:stretch; etc.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ohh sorry ! Wrong example - now everything should be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want everything from the second fiddle + the content in line 3 to align to the center of the container. If that is what you want, I think this fiddle might solve your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/mk3xh1fe/

^ Let me know if that is what you were looking for.

The issue was that, since you're using `display: flex` on the div, and there are several elements within that div, they need to be told to align as a `column` rather than a `row` (which is the default).

Also, I enforced some code styling rules here to your css to follow standards and that, in my opinion, make the css more readable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you - flex-direction: column; fix it.

Comment: Hmmm one more thing... https://jsfiddle.net/hczow0bL/ how to threat additional tag as inline?

Comment: Nest it inside of another container with the other content you want it to be inline with: https://jsfiddle.net/b2936wmy/